# Smartest way to inherit in SASS

Tags: css, sass

I wonder is there a better (shorter) method to inherit than in this example code?

```
span{
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  opacity: 0.6;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
.spanClass{
  @extend span;
  top: 10px;
}
.spanClass2{
  @extend span;
  bottom: 10px;  
}
```

Comment: Only thing I can think of is to write `span, .spanClass, .spanClass2` as one line, then `.spanClass` and `.spanClass2` have their own lines.  It's not shorter, but it's different

Comment: Shorter isn't better per se, but in this case just writing `span.spanClass` in *good ole* CSS is both shorter and more clear. And you don't even need a sass transpiler if this is the only case you got.

Comment: @ntgCleaner what you have suggest is what `@extend` will compile to. Using `@extend` is more friendly. Without using `@extend` you have to remember where in your file the shared style is and manually append classes to it.

Comment: @hungerstar true.  I just don't think there's any better way for him to do it.  I guess I was just suggesting an alternative., which you're right: It's not even SASS at that point